# Cannot find name 'NDEFReader' in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nfc

I'm trying to integrate WebNFC in my angular project, I found only package is `@types/w3c-web-nfc` but when I run application it shows me the error mentioned below:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NDEFReader'.
    
    49       const ndef = new NDEFReader();
```

I've checked few resources that says with ssl it would work but I tried it's not working.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What web browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome on android